# DXL DOORs Need help applying a filter using a loop

Tags: loops, filter, ibm-doors

So i just realized that the current filter i have been using only seems to work properly if the first string it finds is incorrect.

```
Module m = current
Object o = current
Filter f

load view "Standard view"

//column attribute Object Type
insert(column 3)
attribute(column 3, "Object Type")
width(column 3, 100)

f1 = attribute "Object Type" == "Requirement"
f2 = attribute "Object Type" == "Derived Requirement"
f3 = contains(attribute "Object Text", "(Testing) ", true)

for o in m do 
{
f = (f1 || f2) && !(f3)
}
set f
filtering on
refresh current
```

Example: this would be my current table (Not great at making a table)

```
ID|        Module Information            |Object Type
__|______________________________________|____________________
1 | (Teting) this is the incorrect format| Requirements 
__|______________________________________|____________________ 
2 | (Testing) this is also correct format| Derived Requirements  
  | (Test) this is incorrect format      |
__|______________________________________|____________________
3 | (Testing) this is the correct format | Requirements  
  | (Testing) this is the correct format |
__|______________________________________|____________________
4 | (Testing) this is the correct format | Requirements  
  | (Teting) this is incorrect format    |
__|______________________________________|____________________
```

So if i were to run my script here it would only show me

```
ID|        Module Information            |Object Type
__|______________________________________|____________________
1 | (Teting) this is the incorrect format| Requirements
```

and not what i was hoping it would show me:

```
ID|        Module Information            |Object Type
__|______________________________________|____________________
1 | (Teting) this is the incorrect format| Requirements 
__|______________________________________|____________________ 
2 | (Testing) this is also correct format| Derived Requirements  
  | (Test) this is incorrect format      |
__|______________________________________|____________________
4 | (Testing) this is the correct format | Requirements  
  | (Teting) this is incorrect format    |
__|______________________________________|____________________
```

So how would i go about showing the correct view? I assume it's something to do with looping
"Object Text contains" filter but i am unsure how i could go about doing that.

Comment: Any info on how to proceed with this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your DXL is working perfectly. However, you may want to alter your question slightly.

Firstly, your DXL is checking whether `Object Type` is "Requirement" or "Derived Requirement", whereas your test data has "Requirement**s**" and "Derived Requirement**s**".

Secondly your code `f = (f1 || f2) && !(f3)` is checking that the object type is either `Requirement` or `Derived Requirement` and also **does not** contain `"(Testing)"` **anywhere** within the object text. Your code does this, and thus will not give you the result you expect, as the last three objects contain the text `"(Testing)"`.

I assume that what you are after is to check that **not all** of the lines contain `"(Testing)"`, as opposed to **none**. In which case the code would be something like:

```
Module m = current
Object o = current
Regexp REGEX_INVALID = regexp2("\\(Testing\\)")
Regexp REGEX_VALID = regexp2("\\(.*\\)")
Buffer searchText = create
Buffer original = create

//Returns true if Object Text contains any one or more pairs of brackets that do not match (Testing)
bool filterObjectText(string objText)
{
    searchText = objText
    original = objText

    while(REGEX_VALID searchText)
    {
        if (REGEX_INVALID searchText)
        {
            int offset = null
            int subStrLength = null
            findPlainText(tempStringOf(searchText), "(Testing)", offset, subStrLength, true)
            searchText = searchText[offset + subStrLength:]
        }
        else
        {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

filtering off

for o in m do 
{
    string objectType = o."Object Type"
    string objectText = o."Object Text"

    if ((objectType == "Requirements" || objectType == "Derived Requirements") && filterObjectText(objectText))
    {
        accept o
    }
    else
    {
        reject o
    }
}

filtering on
refresh current
```